# How to write a "where not in" query with nested "select" using Query Builder Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can I write the following SQL query in Codeigniter and using Query Builder Class

```
SELECT * FROM products AND id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM purchases)
```

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter's Query Builder Class comes with the function [where_not_in()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where_not_in#CI_DB_query_builder::where_not_in) but you cannot use it with a subquery or custom string. On the other hand you can use the custom string of the [where()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=get_compiled_select#looking-for-specific-data) function this way:

```
$query=$this->db->where('id NOT IN (SELECT `product_id` FROM `purchases`)')
                ->get('products');  
echo $this->db->last_query();die;
```

outputs:

> SELECT * FROM  `products` WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `product_id` FROM
>   `purchases`)

**note:** the query of your question has a syntax error, replace `AND` with `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

This will be the solution if you're strictly looking for `CodeIgniter query` but if you don't mind mingling it with normal SQL queries then @Vickel's answer should do the deed.

```
//first get the data you want to ignore-
$not_in_arr = $this->db->select('product_id')->from('purchases')->get()->result();
```

`where_in` and `where_not_in` expect you to pass an indexed array as the 2nd parameter.

```
//get the data in indexed array format-
foreach($not_in_arr as $not){
    $notin[] = $not->product_id;
}

$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('products')->where_not_in('id', $notin)->get()->result();

echo $this->db->last_query(); //returns- SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` NOT IN('1', '2', '3')
```

Hope this helps you. :)